# How to use expression language in hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I am just looking for a way in which we can use the SpEL in side  hibernate.cfg.xml file? .I want to populate the hibernate.default_schema dynamically using self reference like  java:/comp/env/jdbc/data.[dbschemaname].
Below is my  hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
...
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">${jdbc.user}</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the schema created in MySQL

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbschema_name?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
 
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```